# udev rules official docs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

I am looking official UDEV rules, documents, I have noticed there are changes in udev rules in RHEL 7. But could not find any documents some thing like 'request for changes'.

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: What distribution and version are you running? I am guessing something like RHEL/CentOS/Oracle 7.

Comment: I am using  RHEL 7.

Comment: Ok. I updated your question to reflect this.

Comment: [`man udev`](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/udev.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Check [Product Documentation for Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux/) and look for Technical Notes for your current release and the ones in between from your old release.
- For a quick path: [Google search/ "udev.html" site:access.redhat.com](https://www.google.com/?q=%22udev.html%22%20site:access.redhat.com)